# Is it considered correct to omit curly braces strictly on one-liners?

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style

I am personally *against* omitting curly braces for if-else-statements and I perfectly see why it should be avoided.

However right now I've come accross an interesting use case, example code here:

```
public <E extends RuntimeException> void throwOnFail(final boolean result, final Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
    Objects.requireNonNull(exceptionSupplier);
    if (result) return;
    throw exceptionSupplier.get();
}
```

I personally think this code is:

- As concise as it can get, will show other variants below.
- Not vulnerable to the issue where adding a line will change the logic of the code.

I would set it as a personal rule for myself to *only* use this on control-flow statements.
So practically that means, `return`, `break` and `continue`.

Two alternative versions of this code are shown below.

**Alternative 1**

```
public <E extends RuntimeException> void throwOnFail(final boolean result, final Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
    Objects.requireNonNull(exceptionSupplier);
    if (result) {
        return;
    }
    throw exceptionSupplier.get();
}
```

**Alternative 2**

```
public <E extends RuntimeException> void throwOnFail(final boolean result, final Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
    Objects.requireNonNull(exceptionSupplier);
    if (!result) {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

I would say they both make the code look more complicated for no appereant reason.

Comment: I think it is up to an individual's coding style to some extent. But I strongly dislike having one liners without braces as one can easily skip seeing the statement after the condition if it's on the same line. I would also like to add that your alternatives _do not_ look complicated to me.

Comment: The answer depends on which form you're used to.  That said this is _primarily opinion-based_.

Comment: The method name describes the code as "throws if not result" (and I guess that's roughly what I would put as JavaDoc). I would therefore prefer `if (!result) throw ..` (even as 1 liner) in code simply because that matches the advertised behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it considered correct to omit curly braces strictly on one-liners?

Well there isn't any hard rule on it. But considering the usability case, I'd always use a curly bracket. It makes the code more readable and for junior developer it's easy to understand. Again it's purely a personal/Company(code-standard) choice.

And again in your alternatives, I'd go for the **Alternative2**

```
public <E extends RuntimeException> void throwOnFail(final boolean result, final Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
    Objects.requireNonNull(exceptionSupplier);
    if (!result) {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

**Why?**

1. More concise
2. Less number of lines
3. Logically straight forward

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **Alternative 2**.

Even though omitting the curly braces might make the code prettier and more concise, alternative 2 is the hardest one to misinterpret.

There is a slight chance that someone who throws a quick glance at that function will miss the return statement since its not on its own line, its much harder to make that mistake in alternative 2.

Answer (score 0):

I consider adding `curly braces` everywhere, where a body could be composed of more than one statement `defensive programming`, which prevent subtle logical errors. But in case your team values:

- highly readable code
- hand formatted code

then you are ready to use another rule, which I do apply to my source code:

```
omit `curly braces` when the single statement of a body occurs at the same line.
```

This way you avoid the additional unnecessary tokens, which do do provide anything useful for the reader. But it requires discipline and commitment of a whole team to format the code by hand, or to apply the right formatting rules. I always format my code by hand to make it most readable in those cases, when the formatting rules fail.